# Command not found when executing node.js n package on sudo

Tags: 14.04, nodejs

I'm trying to update my version of node to the latest stable.

Using [this resource](http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs) I was able to:

```
sudo npm install n -g
```

But when I try

```
sudo npm n stable
```

I get:

```
sudo: n: command not found
```

If I run `n stable`, the command is present:

```
n stable
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/n’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/n’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/n’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/n’: Permission denied

     install : node-v0.12.2
       mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/0.12.2
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/n’: Permission denied

  Error: sudo required
```

Comment: Nice idea, but when I do that it returns me 'n: command not found', even though I've dropped the 'sudo'

Comment: sudo sh -c "PATH=$PATH; n stable"  <new line>
sh: 1: n: not found

Comment: No output at all.  That's depresssing :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22792/discussion-between-jonred-and-helio).

Comment: Please post the output of `ls /usr/local/bin/n`

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, `sudo npm install n -g` will install `n` globally, because it has the `-g` parameter (at least on my computer)

Comment: ls: cannot access /usr/local/bin/n: No such file or directory

Comment: Please post the output of `cat ~/.npmrc | grep prefix`

Comment: prefix=/home/jonathan/npm

Comment: I've posted an answer. English isn't my mother tongue, if you encoutered any typo, please edit and fix. Now you can run again `sudo visudo` and revert the changes made to `secure_path` variable. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Surprisingly, your `npm` installation has the global prefix in a folder called `npm` on your home directory, this means that any package installed with the `-g` flag will install on this folder.

You can change this folder to any folder that is on the `sudo` safe path following these steps:

---

**Graphical way:**

1. Open a File Manager (a.k.a Nautilus).
2. Navigate to your home folder.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files.
4. Open a file called `.npmrc` with your favorite text editor.
5. Find a line on that file with this content:

   ```
   prefix=/home/<your_username>/npm
   ```
6. Replace `/home/<your_username>/npm` by a safe path (such as `/usr/local/bin`).
7. Once replaced it will look like this:

   ```
   prefix=/usr/local/bin
   ```
8. Save the file.
9. Run again `sudo npm install n -g`

---

**Terminal way:**

Run this command:

```
sed -i.bak "s%^prefix=.*$%prefix=/usr/local/bin%" ~/.npmrc
```

Comment: I think this nailed it!  It also helped me just now when I updated my npm version, but wouldn' t recognise it.  So, accepted, and thank you!

Comment: Didnt help, still same isssue :/

Comment: This helped me! I didn't have ~/.npmrc file, so I added it and now it works fine

Comment: Beware: this will undo _Option 2_ of  [fixing NPM permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)

Answer (score 41):

I have found solution which worked for me:

```
sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" n stable
```

Found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29400598/861615

Comment: env: n: No such file or directory

Comment: @user3311522 did you use: `sudo npm install n -g` before `sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" n stable` ??

Comment: life saver! Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an Ubuntu forum, but I'm sure this will help someone with the same problem on the RHEL flavours who Googled to here like I did. Perhaps it also works in Ubuntu.

[This is the approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5062718/2036135):

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/n /usr/bin/n
```

Answer (score 5):

This mean you don't have N installed in you system, N is an npm-based node version manager. You can install it by installing first some version of node and then running

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

now you can install the version on node using n command

```
sudo n stable
```

The above will install the latest stable verion

```
sudo n lates
```

this will install the lates version

you can also install the specific version by specifying the version as below

```
sudo n  10.16.0
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid messing up with the `.npm-global` folder as [noted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608661/command-not-found-when-executing-node-js-n-package-on-sudo#comment1349171_609308) by @Edson Horacio Junior, and based on @pohest's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/943401/226163), here is how I fixed it:

```bsh
sudo ln -s /home/<username>/.npm-global/bin/n /usr/local/bin/n
sudo n --version # test it
```

As a note, this probably will not work if you haven't followed npm's steps for [changing the default global directory](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me. Use `nvm` package to download latest node.

1. Install nvm using below command

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash`

2. Create an environment variable to use nvm

```
export NVM_DIR="${XDG_CONFIG_HOME/:-$HOME/.}nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

3. Try `nvm -v` if it cannot see `nvm` installed, run the script below

`command -v nvm`

4. To install node run command below

`nvm install node`

5. After restarting the terminal, try to check the version of node, it should be updated

`node -v`

More info here: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers above worked for me. This however this did:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/bin/n stable
```

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem, this is how you can solve it:

1. Get npm config prefix

   ```bsh
   npm config get prefix 
   // get -> ${myhome}/.npm-global
   ```
2. Add the following lines in `.zshrc`

   ```bsh
   # Specify `n` to put the version of `node` in the `.n` directory.
   export N_PREFIX=${myhome}/.npm-global/.n

   # Make `nman` command work
   export PATH=${myhome}/.npm-global/bin:$PATH

   # Add this line to use `node -v` command
   export PATH=${myhome}/.npm-global/.n/bin:$PATH
   ```

**Reference:** [GitHub - tj/n: Node version management](https://github.com/tj/n#optional-environment-variables)

> <sup>**Editor's note:** This answer was originally written in Chinese and has been translated and edited using online tools. To see the original answer, refer [Revision #1](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1177808/1)</sup>